# How do items effect Melee and Ranged champs?

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm talking about items like Runaan's Hurricane and Ravenous Hydra. How do they effect certain champs like Jayce or Nidalee where they can switch between ranged and melee? Also how does Runaan's Hurricane effect Gangplank's Q Parrrley?

> This ability can critically strike and applies on-hit effects,
>   including his passive.

Does this mean it will apply Runaan's Hurricane's unique passive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Jayce, Nidalee or Elise are in their ranged mode, Runaan's Hurricane applies to their attacks. When they are in melee mode, Ravenous Hydra is in action. [Here's some old discussion about it on League of Legends forums.](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=2875709)

> You could probably buy both, but they would only work with their respective melee/ranged attacks.
>
> The raw stats work in either mode. (+70 AS, +50 AD, +15 regen all the time)
> The passives and Tiamat's active only work in their respective modes.

[Gangplank's Parrrley works with Ravenous Hydra](http://youtu.be/OUr7Patko1c?t=1m14s), but not with Runaan's Hurricane. That is because the champion is melee and that seems to dictate the attacks.

Comment: I didn't expect Ravenous Hydra to work with Parrrley. Thanks so much!